# How to get the selected dropdown value on submit in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I am trying to get the value of selected drop-down value and send it to another controller. And by using that drop-down value below values need to be changed by fetching the data from the database.

Below is the code I have tried.

```
<form action="{{{ url("/getDetailsBynumber/$_POST['number']") }}}" method="post">
<select name="number" id="number">
    <option selected="selected">Select number id</option>
    <?php     
    $numberArray = json_decode($number_id, true);       

    for ($i = 0 ; $i<=$number_count ; $i++) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $numberArray[$i]["number_value"] ?>"><?php echo $numberArray[$i]["number_value"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Try with only two {{ like this : ="{{url("/getD...

Answer (score 6):

You need to add **name** attribute to **select** tag. As a result when form submitted it will send selected value with it's name. For example:

```
<select name="product_id">
   <option value="1">Cup</option> <!-- Suppose this option selected -->
   <option value="2">Pen</option>
   <option value="3">Book</option>
</select>
```

If you submit form, you can get selected value in your controller as follows:

```
public function methodName(Request $request)
{
  // $request->product_id is name attribute of your select tag
  print_r($request->product_id); // It will print out 1 which is value of Cup
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="{{ url("/getDetailsBynumber/") . $_POST['number'] }}" method="post">
<select name="number" id="number">
    <option selected="selected">Select number id</option>
    <?php     
    $numberArray = json_decode($number_id, true);       

    for ($i = 0 ; $i<=$number_count ; $i++) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $numberArray[$i]["number_value"] ?>"><?php echo $numberArray[$i]["number_value"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to get state name after submit if validation fail incase then it works 
on load of page you can get the country id like this

```
var countryid = $('#opt_country').val();
```

after that base on that you have to find state_id

like this

```
if (countryid != '')
{

    $.ajax({
        url: base_path + 'getstate',
        type: "POST",
        data: {in_country_id: countryid},
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (statedata) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(statedata);
            console.log(obj);
            if (obj.SUCC_FLAG == 1)
            {
                for (var i in obj)
                {
                    console.log(obj);
                    var id = obj[i].in_state_id;
                    var name = obj[i].st_state_name;
                    if (id == stateid)
                    {
                        $("#opt_state").append("<option value='" + id + "' selected >" + name.toString() + "</option>");
                    } else {
                        $("#opt_state").append("<option value='" + id + "'>" + name.toString() + "</option>");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                confirm('We are unable to load State');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("server error");
        }

    });
}
```

and after that you can get the state so here is my example to get state after submit the page